# Better way to combine Word embedding to get embedding of a sentence

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-processing, word-embedding

I have seen in many kaggle kernels and tutorials, average word embeddings is considered to get embedding of a sentence. But, i am wondering if this is a correct approach.Since it discards the positional information of the words in the sentence. is there a better way to combine embedding? maybe hierarchically combining them in a particular way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a simple but yet effective approach, [Sif embedding](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SyK00v5xx) is perfectly fine. It averages word vector in a sentence and removes its first principal component. It is much superior to averaging word vectors. The code available online [here](https://github.com/PrincetonML/SIF/tree/master/examples). Here is the main part:

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=1, random_state=rand_seed, n_iter=20)
svd.fit(all_vector_representation)
svd = svd.components_

XX2 = all_vector_representation - all_vector_representation.dot(svd.transpose()) * svd
```

Where `all_vector_representation` is the average embedding of all sentences in your dataset.

Other sophisticated approaches also exist out there like [ELMO](https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2), [Transformer](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/1) and etc.

Comment: What is the intuition behind removing the first component. Is it remove some sort of population stratification?

Answer (score 2):

I learned everything I know from the above post by Amir and glancing at the paper. I was not a fan of the code base linked and do not think Amir's code reflects what the paper says so I will add extremely simple code that does exactly what the paper proposes.

```
def SIF_Embedding(X,p,a=1e-3):
    # X is the concatenated word embeddings (n,m) 
    # p is the probability of each word     (n,1)
            
    U,_,_ = np.linalg.svd(np.matmul(X.transpose(),X))
    U = U[:,0]
        
    mV = np.matmul( ( a / (a + p) ) , X)
    mV /= X.shape[0]
    mV -= U * np.matmul(U.transpose(), mV)
    
    return mV
```